# Keep duplicated row from a specific data frame after append

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames (`df1` & `df2`), after a merge, I find two duplicate rows (same values for  three columns:`["ID","City","Year"]`). I would like to keep one of the duplicate rows which comes from `df2` .

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {
      'ID':[7,2],
     'City': ["Berlin","Paris"],
    'Year':[2012,2000],
    'Number':[62,43],}

data2 ={
    'ID': [7, 5],
    'City': ["Berlin", "London"],
    'Year':[2012,2019],
    'Number': [60, 100], }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df_merged= df1.append(df2)
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Expected output:

```
    ID    City  Year  Number
0   2   Paris  2000      43
1   7  Berlin  2012      60
2   5  London  2019     100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
new = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
           .drop_duplicates(subset=["ID", "City", "Year"],
                            keep="last",
                            ignore_index=True))
```

`append` will be gone in near future, use `pd.concat` there please. Then `drop_duplicates` over the said columns while `keep="last"`:

```py
In [376]: df1
Out[376]:
   ID    City  Year  Number
0   7  Berlin  2012      62
1   2   Paris  2000      43

In [377]: df2
Out[377]:
   ID    City  Year  Number
0   7  Berlin  2012      60
1   5  London  2019     100

In [378]: (pd.concat([df1, df2])
     ...:     .drop_duplicates(subset=["ID", "City", "Year"],
     ...:                      keep="last",
     ...:                      ignore_index=True))
Out[378]:
   ID    City  Year  Number
0   2   Paris  2000      43
1   7  Berlin  2012      60
2   5  London  2019     100
```

ignore_index makes it again 0, 1, 2 after `drop_duplicates` disturbs it